# image anchor and text not aligned vertically

Tags: css

I have below menus

```
    <ul id="fMenu">
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/connect/Facebook.png">Be a Fan</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/connect/Twitter.png">Follow Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/connect/Google+.png">+1</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/connect/Flickr.png">Flickr</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/connect/Tumblr.png">Tumblr</a></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that link text is displayed somewhat below the image i want the text to be against the middle of the image

Regards Jane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to set the [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) property on your image, most likely `middle` or `text-bottom`

```
<img ... style="vertical-align:middle;" />
```

EDIT:

since you posted some code, do it in stylesheet:

```
ul#fMenu li a img {vertical-align:middle;}
```

Comment: of course, this is just a guess since your question is not very descriptive and says '... aligned horizontally'